# Как сделать свайп плавнее

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте! У меня есть объект, который нужно перемещать свайпом вверх-вниз(по y). Проблема заключается в том - что объект дёргается(После того, как я один раз свайп использовал(обьект остался там, где должен), второй раз когда я использую свайп - он дёргается, словно перемещается **на какие-то координаты, возможно начальные**).
Эту тему с тапами, свайпами и т.п я совсем не понимаю.
Как мне всё же сделать так, что бы оно не дёргалось?

Вот код:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform textTransform;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 startPos;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 directionPos;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: // Начало
                startPos.y = touch.position.y; // Первый тап
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved: // Движение
                directionPos.y = touch.position.y - startPos.y;
                break;
        }
        textTransform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, directionPos.y); // Перемещение
    }
}
```

Comment: Обнули directionPos.y в TouchPhase.Began

Comment: @Yaroslav не помогло

Comment: `directionPos.y = touch.position.y;` обнули в смысле не 0, а стартовая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал расчет смещения объекта относительно его начальной позиции, а не начальной позиции тача:

```
private float touchOffset;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: 
                touchOffset = touch.position.y - textTransform.localPosition.y;
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                textTransform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, touch.position.y - touchOffset);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Объект уходит как-то вверх, когда я нажимаю и провожу внизу

Comment: @Артем вскрылись новые детали, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Артем обновил еще раз, оптимизировал слегка

Answer (score 1):

```
[SerializeField] private Transform textTransform;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 startPos;
[SerializeField] private Vector2 directionPos;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: // Начало
                startPos.y = textTransform.position.y; // Первый тап
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved: // Движение
                directionPos.y = touch.position.y - startPos.y;
                break;
        }
        textTransform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, directionPos.y); // Перемещение
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает ещё хуже, чем мой вариант, извините

Comment: ну ладно. Я пытался